# How return multiple tags inside a if/else using XQuery?

Tags: xquery

I have to do something like:

```
declare function xf:NameOfXQ($myIn as element(ns2:myIn))
    as element() {
        <ns0:tagIn>

            <myObj>
               {
                for $var in $myValueOfVar
                    return
                        if ($var= "X") then
                            <tagA>A</tagA>
                            <tagB>B</tagB>
                            <tagC>C</tagC>
                        else
                            <tagD>D</tagD>
                }
            </myObj>

        </ns0:tagIn>
};
```

But when the xquery is build, my project says "**Invalid expression, expecting ELSE, found '>'**"
I try then use 4 IF's, one to fill each tag, like:

```
declare function xf:NameOfXQ($myIn as element(ns2:myIn))
    as element() {
        <ns0:tagIn>

            <myObj>
            {
            for $var in $myValueOfVar
                return
                    if ($var= "X") then
                        <tagA>A</tagA>
                    else
                        ()
                    if ($var= "X") then
                        <tagB>B</tagB>
                    else
                        ()
                    if ($var= "X") then
                        <tagC>C</tagC>
                    else
                        ()
                    if ($var != "X") then
                        <tagD>D</tagD>
                    else
                        ()
            }
            </myObj>

        </ns0:tagIn>
};
```

Then my project says "**Invalid expression: unexpected token: if**"
How I can do it correctly?

Comment: An XML fragment must have a root tag to be considered valid, which is why your XQuery doesn't compile. You might be able to use a sequence of XML fragments instead, e.g. `(<tagA>A</tagA>, <tagB/>, ...)`

Comment: You mean a father tag, like <tagFather><tagA/><tagB/>...</tagFather>? Because if is something like that, I have, I just forgot to put in code of question. If is other thing, can you explain a little, please? Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes a parent tag, but your FLWOR expression itself should return a valid XML fragment. I'm writing a sample for the sequence use, I haven't written XQuery in years so I'd rather test it. I'll comment back if I succeed.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll complete the question. Thanks for help, I'm starting to use xquery these days.

Comment: Alright, returning a sequence of XML fragments instead of a single XML fragment works ; see http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/219e8413be6a63eefe68da2b5097cab5 for a sample

Comment: In short just add parenthesis around your multiple XML tags and separate them with a comma

Comment: Hm, ok, I'll adapt and try this and if works I'll awnser you. Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron, thanks man, you way is really correct! Before I trying, I find in some documentation this syntax. Can you please use your solution in an answer, so I can mark this as correct? =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XQuery doesn't consider multiple consecutive tags as syntactically correct, an XML fragment must have a root tag to be valid.

It however allows you to use sequence types with the syntax `(item1, item2, ... itemN)` which you can use to let the `return` clause of your FLWOR expression yield multiple XML tags :

```
for $var in $myValueOfVar
    return
        if ($var= "X") then
            (
                <tagA>A</tagA>,
                <tagB>B</tagB>,
                <tagC>C</tagC>
            )
        else
            <tagD>D</tagD>
```